# An article with a title of a company / brand / project before a common noun

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, proper-nouns

Would you put an article before a proper noun / a title that precedes a common noun when speaking about brands, firms, et cetera? For example:

> [A/The] Formula One staff responds to fans' questions.
>
> [A/The] Calvin Klein team is being criticised for the new ad.
>
> [An/The] Amazon.com personnel works hard on improving the service.
>
> [A/The] Stop AIDS Project team seeks for volunteers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a compound noun, the final noun is the one that determines the need for an article, regardless of the makeup and length of other elements of the compound noun.

For example, if the final noun is uncountable, no indefinite article is required: if is countable, an indefinite article is required.

> Barbados **sugar** is dark brown
> A Barbados amateur cricket team **member** was injured.

Regarding your sentences:

> 1. [The] Formula One staff respond to fans' questions.

If you are talking about formula one staff in general, no indefinite article is required because in British English [staff](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/staff) counts as plural (in Indian English it can also be singular- the equivalent of "staff member" in British English). A definite article is required if you are talking about a particular group of formula one staff (for example, those present at this event).

> 2. The Calvin Klein team is being criticised for the new ad.

There is only one Calvin Klein team, it is specific, so a definite article is required.

> 3. [The] Amazon.com personnel work hard on improving the service.
>    Same as (1).

> 4. The Stop AIDS Project team seeks for volunteers.

There is only one Stop AIDS Project team: it is specific, so a definite article is required.

Comment: Many thanks for your comprehensive response <3